# How to replace double quotes?

Tags: php, preg-replace

I have a string: "Blah blah blah "blah" blah blah", and I need to replace quotes on this string to «Blah blah blah «blah» blah blah»

I was trying to use this script:

```
$m=preg_replace('/([^\s>])\\\"/s',"$1&raquo;",$m);
$m=preg_replace('/\\\"([^\s])/s',"&laquo;$1",$m);
```

But when the string beginning from the space, i have something like that:

```
 »Some text» Some text Some text
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Your example uses "smart" quotes but I assume since you're using regular expressions, that you will actually be replacing straight quotes?

Comment: I can use just regexp. Yes, original text use straight quotes and they are the same. It's a problem. I need to replace "these quotes" to «these quotes» on the text. (Sorry for my bad English)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most direct approach might be to use lookarounds to detect it the quote is directly before a word or directly after.

```
$m = preg_replace('/"(?=\w)/', '«', $m);
$m = preg_replace('/(?<=\w)"/', '»', $m);
```

This will work well on your example, but may be too simplistic. You might want to go further and look for a word charactor or punctuation so "blah blah." will match as well. That would make the second example something like this: `/(?<=[\w,.?!\)])"/`

Answer (score 0):

```
$str = '"Test string "blabla" sdf "dd" dffdsf"';
$result = preg_replace('/(\s)"([^"]+)"(\s)/', '$1«$2»$3', $str);
$result = preg_replace('/^"(.*?)"$/', '«$1»', $result); // replace first and last quotes
```

This code works only for strings without many nested quotes. This code don't work for string:

> "Test "string is "test" test" test"

Answer (score -1):

may be such way ?

```
$m=str_replace("&lt;","",$m); 
$m=str_replace("&rt;","",$m);
```